# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c

I have read other posts that get the "makes pointer from integer w/o cast" error but I am confused about exactly what it means. Is it saying that the function `gets` makes the int variable `input` a pointer by default if I don't cast (cast meaning say `gets ((int) input`) )?

```
int directions() 
{   
    int input;

    printf("Type '1', '2', etc to see a problem or type '(add an 'all' option to see a     list of all the problems)\n");
    gets( input);

    switch ( input) {
        case 1: euler1();
        case 2: euler2();
    }

    return input;
}

int main()
{   
    printf("Welcome to Project Euler's Problems in C!\n");
    directions();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile... unless there's an implicit conversion from int to char*.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`, not even in demonstration code.  Use `fgets()` exclusively, even if it wears your fingers to the bone typing the two extra arguments.

Comment: Even the man page says **Never  use gets().**

Comment: Did you read the gets manual (http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets)? What's its parameter type? Why didn't you do that before you posted here?

Comment: @Borgleader: The call is a constraint violation, which requires a diagnostic message. gcc, in its default mode, typically prints non-fatal warnings for integer/pointer type mismatches. IMHO this is unfortunate, but it doesn't violate the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `gets()` is a `char*`, a pointer to a buffer. It doesn't return an `int`.  If you look at some [documentation on `gets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/), you'll see how it is properly used.

Once you read the string in, you'll need to use [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) to convert from ASCII to an integer.

Note that you are better off using something like [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)`(stdin, "%d", &input);` to scan the input stream for the input you desire.

Comment: There is no proper/safe way to use `gets()`; it isn't even part of the current standard C library (at long, long last!).  It was dropped from C2011.  You do go on to mention use something else, but...IMNSHO, you can't tromp on the use of `gets()` hard enough.  However, the questionner also needs to be taught how to fish; finding out the interface to `gets()` is important.

Answer (score 0):

first argument to `gets()` is a `char*` always (pointer to  buffer). It doesn't return an int or other datatype.

Using something like `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &input);` to scan the input stream for the input you want.

Use `gets()` as little as possible, use `fgets`.

happy to code:)

Answer (score -1):

`gets()` does not get an int. Use the `atoi()` to convert.

```
char *s;
s = gets(buff)
input = atoi(s);
```

Comment: `buff` is not declared anywhere; and `s` is redundant